# Updating the case owner of a salesforce using Python

Tags: python, salesforce

I am trying to update the case owner in salesforce using simple salesforce. But When i try to change the case owner it is not getting assigned and the case gets into Assignment Error Queue.

My python code is :

```
headers = {'Sforce-Auto-Assign': 'False'}

sf.Case.update("500V*******",{"OwnerId":"005***********"},headers)
```

I want the case owner to be updated with the given owner id and do i have to include some more fields or headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using python beatbox.

Installation of beabox for python 3.X :

pip install -e git+https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox@master#egg=beatbox

Code :

import beatbox

sf_username = "username"

sf_password = "password"

sf_api_token = "token"

sf_client = beatbox.Client()

sf_client.serverUrl = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/20.0'

password = str("%s%s" % (sf_password, sf_api_token))

sf_client.login(sf_username, password)

object_dict = {'OwnerID': 'ownerid','type':'Case','Id': 'caseid'}

results = sf_client.update(object_dict)

results

Using this i was able to update the case owner successfully .